# How to access the SelectField options when we click on the text or icon in input adornment in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've used Material UI TextField with 'Select' prop to make it as SelectField. I have text in Input adornment. I need to access the SelectField options when I click on the input adornment text. I don't understand how to do that. I am providing the sandbox link below. Can Anyone help me with this? Thanks you.

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-bykj0?file=/demo.tsx

code:

```
import React from "react";
import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme, fade } from "@material- 
  ui/core/styles";
 import {TextField, Typography} from "@material-ui/core";
import { TextValidator } from 'react-material-ui-form-validator';
import InputAdornment from '@material-ui/core/InputAdornment';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';

 const currencies = [
 {
 value: 'USD',
 label: '$',
 },
  {
  value: 'EUR',
 label: '€',
  },
 {
 value: 'BTC',
 label: '฿',
 },
 {
value: 'JPY',
 label: '¥',
 },
 ];

 const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
 createStyles({
 root: {
 "& > *": {
margin: theme.spacing(1),
width: "25ch"
 }
 }
})
);

 const useStylesReddit = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
createStyles({


selectClass: {
minWidth: '20px'
 }

})
 ); 

 export const MovingOutRedditTextField = (TextFieldProps) => {
 const classes = useStylesReddit();
  const { id } = TextFieldProps;
  return (
  <TextField
  id={id}
  InputLabelProps={{
  shrink: true,

  }}

  InputProps={{
   classes,
   disableUnderline: true,
    endAdornment: (
     <InputAdornment position="end">
     <Typography
      color="textSecondary"
      >
      currency
      </Typography>
     </InputAdornment>
    )
    }}
   {...TextFieldProps}
    />
    );
    };

   export default function BasicTextFields() {
   const classes = useStyles();
   const [currency, setCurrency] = React.useState('EUR');

   const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
   setCurrency(event.target.value);
   };

    return (


    <MovingOutRedditTextField
   select
   classes={{select:classes.selectClass}}
   required
   style={{width:'400px'}}
   label="Return"
   id="securityDepoistReturn"
   value={currency}

   variant="filled"
   >
  {currencies.map((option) => (
    <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
      {option.label}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
  </MovingOutRedditTextField>
  );
   }
```

Comment: can you make an image from what look you expect?

Answer (score 0):

The problem exists already for a long time and it's being discussed in Github. Here, check it out.

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/17799

It seems there is no good solution for now. Also you forgot to add onChange method to your TextField, so you can't change the currency. The InputAdornment if usually for the input fields. You better check on github, you may find some solution there.